# FileListEntityProcessor + java heap exception

Tags: solr, indexing

I am trying to index huge data from file system and data size is few terabytes. I am using FileListEntityProcessor with TikaEntityProcessor.

data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="bin" type="BinFileDataSource" />
    <document>
        <entity name="f" dataSource="null" rootEntity="true"
            processor="FileListEntityProcessor" transformer="TemplateTransformer"
            baseDir="//mathworks/devel/bat/A/logs/66048/"
            fileName=".*\.*" onError="skip" recursive="true">

            <field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="path" />
            <field column="fileSize" name="size"/>
            <field column="fileLastModified" name="lastmodified" />

            <entity name="file" dataSource="bin" processor="TikaEntityProcessor" url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text" onError="skip"
           rootEntity="true">
                <field column="text" name="text"/>   
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I am stating jetty server with -Xms1024m -Xmx10240m , still i keep getting java heap exception although my machine is pretty good.
I faced the same issue while indexing database but my problem was solved with "batchSize=-1". Can I do something like that here? or is there anything which wouldindex terabytes of data from file system.

EDIT: I am trying to index log files which are all text files.I dont see any specific document which fails the process. After one and half hours it just shows the exception.

```
INFO: [tika] webapp=null path=null params={event=newSearcher&q=static+newSearcher+warming+query+from+solrconfig.xml} hits=872 status=0 QTime=1
Oct 8, 2013 6:04:27 PM org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener newSearcher
INFO: QuerySenderListener done.
Oct 8, 2013 6:04:27 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore registerSearcher
INFO: [tika] Registered new searcher Searcher@15cab4c0 main
Oct 8, 2013 6:04:27 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher close
INFO: Closing Searcher@67071180 main
        fieldValueCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
        filterCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
        queryResultCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=3,evictions=0,size=3,warmupTime=5,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
        documentCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=10,evictions=0,size=10,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Oct 8, 2013 6:04:33 PM org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish
INFO: {deleteByQuery=*:*,add=[(null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), ... (20157 adds)]} 0 4
Oct 8, 2013 6:04:33 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:264)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:375)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:445)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:426)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:621)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:327)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:225)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:759)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:619)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputField.toString(SolrInputField.java:200)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.AbstractMap.toString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument.toString(SolrInputDocument.java:182)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.upload(SolrWriter.java:68)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler$1.upload(DataImportHandler.java:293)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:723)
        ... 6 more

Oct 8, 2013 6:04:33 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
INFO: start rollback
Oct 8, 2013 6:04:33 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
INFO: end_rollback
```

Thanks in adcvance.
Prerna

Comment: Can you see on which specific document the indexing process fails? Could you post the document type (PDF, Word, ...) and the size of the document? The very best would be, if you could put the doc somewhere. I'd like to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am trying to index log files which are all text files.I dont see any specific document which fails the process. After one and half hours it just shows the exception. I have edited the question to give more info.